# Putting lock on Java object before serialization

Tags: java, serialization

If I have a straightforward Java object with two instance variables:

```
class SerializeMe implements Serializable{

private Foo foo;
private Bar bar;

}
```

if the `Foo` and `Bar` classes implement the Serializable interface I should be good to go. But my question is, if I am in the process of serializing this class `SerializeMe`, isn't it very possible that in a multi-threaded environment that the state of `foo` or `bar` variables might change while the serialization is taking place?

How can I ensure that the overall state of the parent class `SerializeMe` will not change during serialization?

Is the best way to simply create a lock on the object you wish to serialize?

Comment: The answer is yes, it's very possible that state could change during serialization. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3077703/java-serialization-of-objects-in-a-multithreaded-environment and let us know if you still have questions.

Comment: Yes, it is quite possible, and it is not thread safe. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8724082/serializing-in-java-automatic-thread-safety

Comment: The best way is not to try to serialize objects that might be subject to concurrent modification. Serialization should generally be performed at well-defined points in application flow, not whenever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Serialization is not thread safe.

You can

```
synchronize(object){
 serialize(object)
}
```

But if any other thread already has references to Foo or bar they can modify it.

If you need to modify the serialization of a class you need to implement void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream).

```
private synchronized void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException {
  synchronized(foo){
    synchronized(bar){
      out.defaultWriteObject();
}
}
}
```

This is out my head so please test it.

[EDIT]As Peter Lawrey noted it is synchronized

Comment: I think you meant `synchronized` instead of `synchronize`